# DITA map within a DITA map

Tags: dita, dita-ot

I wish to have two levels of DITAMAP:

- front-matter: about, contact-us, *link* to parts catalog
- parts-catalog: catalog, organised by 3 categories (cat-*xxx*)

The front-matter would also have a link to the parts catalog.

I'm facing this issue: when I include the link to the parts-catalog in the front-matter map, DITA-OT instead inserts the 3 child categories.

[image: sample output]

Is it possible to just insert a *link* to the parts catalog map in the front-matter map?

## Demo:

[image: map screenshot]

### Update

Based on new knowledge I realise it's not good practice to combine two maps in DITA, and it is better to adopt a strategy that builds the document from a single map.

Comment: Could you please paste both maps here? To be honest, I do not understand the question and the problem.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I've realised that producing a document from two DITA maps goes against the intended publishing model, and won't do me any favours.  I'll just use a single map file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on new knowledge I realise it's not good practice to combine two maps in DITA, and it is better to adopt a strategy that builds the document from a single map.

Comment: You can nest maps without any problems and that's common practice. If you share examples, I can maybe give a better answer.

Comment: I've added some screenshots that I hope explain it a little better.  I don't want the lower level map to be embedded, I just want to link to it.

Comment: I do not see a problem with your code. You can also use the convenience element **`<mapref>`**, see https://www.oxygenxml.com/dita/1.3/specs/langRef/base/mapref.html

Maybe you have issues, because you have not set the context in the DITA Maps Manager view correctly, see https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/26.0/ug-editor/topics/dita-maps-manager.html